# DASK - MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape and data type int64

Tags: dask

Getting error...

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (15145488917,) and data type int64

...when attempting the following merge...

```
master = dd.merge(df1, df2)
```

Previous code is...

```
df1.count().compute()
```

...with output...

```
den    312019
num    312019
dtype: int64
```

...and...

```
df2.count().compute()
```

...with output...

```
den    970531
num    970531
dtype: int64
```

Same operation works in pandas with no issues.

Comment: I recomment producing an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: OK I'll try.  Thanks.